# Partitioning $\mathbb{R}$ given a sequence summing to $1$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, and suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive numbers such that $\Sigma a_n = 1$.

Does there exist a partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into measurable sets $D_n$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \chi_{D_n} = a_n \int_{\mathbb{R}} f$?

My intuition is that this is true, but I'm unsure how to go about proving this.

Answer (score 1):

First split up $\mathbb R$ into $P = \{x: f(x) \ge 0\}$ and $N = \{x: f(x) < 0\}$, and deal with these separately.  Essentially, this reduces us to the case $f \ge 0$.
Then take $D_i = (P \cap I_i) \cup (N \cap J_i)$ for appropriately defined intervals 
$I_i$ and $J_i$...